# Mandrill - Messages sent through TEST and Live have different Styling

Tags: mandrill

When I send a test message through the Mandrill Dashboard it appears like this
[image]

When the message is sent out initiated through a ruby transaction this is whats being received.
[image]

This is happening across all Email Clients Mobile, Web, Desktop.

We have adjusted the merge language from Handlebars to Mailchimp and tried everything else we can think of

Good Email
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4MsSwXSSSkSWUFLYnd2S1FlX0E/view?usp=sharing

Bad Email
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4MsSwXSSSkSVUI0SURBREJ0aXM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I am unable to add my code because it exceeds the character limit

Comment: This sounds like something you discuss with mandrill support?

Comment: Thanks Burhan, already sent them a message was hoping maybe someone on stack could help sooner

Answer (score 0):

I have run into similar problems in my attempts to use MailChimp + Mandrill. You are right, the MailChimp template editor does not support handlebars and will behave erratically if you use any handlebars template languages merge tags. Here are three things I'd check:

1. When sending your app, be sure that your merge language is set to MailChimp and that you are inlining your styles.
2. All handlebar merge tags are replaced - even ones in hidden fields like anchors on links
3. Be sure that your font families do not have double quotes or `&quot;` around the fallbacks. If this makes it into your mandrill templates (and it can if you use a font like Lato) then future styles are ignored.